# Can't scale or move object

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I can't adjust the scale or even move a model in Object Mode. I've tried every answer to the similar questions I found on here including:

-Making sure I have 'Manipulate origins' deactivated with none of the 'Affect Only' boxes ticked(Origins, Locations and Parents).

-As far as I'm aware, the object isn't locked

I've attached the screenshot of the Blender file.

If I could get some tips that'd be fab as I'm a beginner to Blender and I'm aware this is probably a simple issue.

Thanks[image]

Comment: in the Outliner, click on the funnel icon, display the arrow icon (selectable) and make sure it is enabled for your object

Comment: @moonboots But if _Selectable_  was disabled it wouldn't show as being selected in the 3D Viewport, or is it possible somehow?

Comment: Oops you're right. Maybe she should share her file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots A blend file is a good idea. The colour of the selected object indicates (assuming default viewport colour settings) that it's not the active object, but even if there's another active object selected she should be able to move them altogether. So at first it seems odd behaviour.

Comment: @Anna-RoseWain Now that I realized that the object doesn't seem to be the active one: are you sure the one you want to move isn't locked or has _Affect Only_ enabled? Because if you have a different active object, those are the values that you see.